# $\mathrm{Supp}(\mathrm{Exc}(f))=\mathrm{Supp}(K_X-f^*K_Y)?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a log resolution of normal varieties, let $\mathrm{Exc}(f)$ be the locus (the complement in $X$ of the largest open where $f$ is an isomorphism).

Is there an example of $f$, such that some codimension $1$ component of $\mathrm{Exc}(f)$ does not appear in the support of $K_X-f^*K_Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking I don't think it makes sense to talk about the support of $K_X-f^*K_Y$. Both $K_X$ and $K_Y$ (and hence the expression you write) are *linear equivalence classes* of divisors, rather than actual divisors, so their support is not well-defined.

In spite of that, I think I get the motivation of your question; if so the answer is "yes". Let $f$ be the minimal resolution of a du Val singularity (a.k.a. Kleinian singularity, rational double point). Then $\operatorname{Exc}(f)$ is a collection of rational curves, in particular has at least 1 codimension 1 component, but $K_X=f^*K_Y$.

Comment: Let me just expand on the first comment to the answer. In birational geometry, when we use this kind of formulas, there is the following implicit working assumption: we fix a Weil divisor $K_X$ in its linear equivalence class, and for every birational morphism $\pi \colon Y \rightarrow X$ we choose the unique Weil divisor $K_Y$ in the linear equivalence class of the canonical such that $\pi_* K_Y = K_X$. Once this is assumed, the difference $K_Y-\pi^*K_X$ is well defined and independent of the initial choice of $K_X$.